# How to send database table to another user in Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have built an app in which users create a list, after pressing submit button the list of things is stored in database table called "lists". and on homepage all the lists are shown in grid format. Now what i want is user to send a specific list to another user so they can add it in their list. How am I supposed to do it?

Comment: Have you considered transforming the table to a json object, sending the object, and transforming it back to a table on the receiving end?

Comment: no, can you please explain further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to reform your list in a JSON format and save it in Firebase
then the other user can read it and reformate it to another list ( or save it in a local database)

Comment: thank you, but i am wondering how to delete data after the another user has added data to his device

Comment: when the first user sends the data, you can also write code to delete it from the device at the same time. the data is always in Firebase and when the other user receive that data you can also write code to delete data from Firebase.